# Pass JSX object as a string

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm new to React and trying to pass a JSX object as a width into a bootstrap progress bar.

I don't know if you can convert JSX to a string but how would I give the progress bar a width?

```
        <p>Vat 1 : {details.v1} Litres -  % Full</p> 

            <div className='progress'>
              <div className='progress-bar'
                   role='progressbar'
                   aria-valuenow='70'
                   aria-valuemin='0'
                   aria-valuemax='100'
                  style={{width: '{details.v1}'+'%'}}>
                <span className='sr-only'>{parseFloat(details.v1*10)} % Complete</span>
             </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you're trying to do is:

```js
<p>Vat 1 : {details.v1} Litres -  % Full</p> 
<div className='progress'>
  <div
    className='progress-bar'
    role='progressbar'
    aria-valuenow='70'
    aria-valuemin='0'
    aria-valuemax='100'
    style={{width: details.v1 + '%'}}>
  <span className='sr-only'>{parseFloat(details.v1*10)} % Complete</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Once you're inside a pair of curly braces, you're in a javascript context so you can leave off any additional curly braces unless you're defining an object literal.

In fact, your style object *is* an object literal. The above is equivalent to:

```js
// somewhere up above
var style = {
  width: details.v1 + '%'
};

// later
<p>Vat 1 : {details.v1} Litres -  % Full</p> 
<div className='progress'>
  <div
    className='progress-bar'
    role='progressbar'
    aria-valuenow='70'
    aria-valuemin='0'
    aria-valuemax='100'
    style={style}>
  <span className='sr-only'>{parseFloat(details.v1*10)} % Complete</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, if you're able to use ES6 (ES2015 aka "new" javascript) you can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and write it a little more cleanly:

```js
style={{width: `${details.v1}%`}}>
```

Having said that, you should probably be passing a `prop` to this component from somewhere else to control this value, so that when it changes, so, too, does your component.

Or better yet, maybe wrap this code in a `<ProgressBar />` component that maybe takes a `progress` prop like `<ProgressBar progress={75}/>`.

Comment: Thanks Danny, it makes sense to wrap it in a component.

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest inline styles here. You can make an object that has all of your styles and just pass that in directly to the JSX:

https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html

```
var divStyle = {
  color: 'white',
  backgroundImage: 'url(' + imgUrl + ')',
  WebkitTransition: 'all', // note the capital 'W' here
  msTransition: 'all' // 'ms' is the only lowercase vendor prefix
};

ReactDOM.render(<div style={divStyle}>Hello World!</div>, mountNode);
```

Answer (score 0):

Might I also suggest checking out react-bootstrap:
https://react-bootstrap.github.io/

```
const progressInstance = (
  <ProgressBar now={60} />
);

ReactDOM.render(progressInstance, mountNode);
```